# Bayesian VAR: Derivation of predictive distribution for reduced form VAR

Tags: bayesian, posterior, vector-autoregression, moments

I have a standard reduced form VAR of type without intercept: $y_t = A_{1}y_{t−1} + \ldots + A_py_{t−p} + e_t$, $e_t \sim N(0,Σ)$.

I need to derive the predictive posterior distribution $p(y_{T+h}|y_{T} , \ldots, y_1)$ in the general case for $h=1,2,3,\ldots$ and define its moments.

I already exhausted many textbooks and couldn't find a solution. If anyone has an idea how to solve this problem, it would be really helpful!

Comment: The posterior predictive is $p(y_{T+h}|\mathbf{y}_{1:T}) = \int_{A} f\left(y_{T+h}|\mathbf{y}_{1:T},\mathbf{\alpha}_{1:p}\right) g\left(\mathbf{\alpha}_{1:p}|\mathbf{y}_{1:T} \right) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\alpha}$ where $\alpha = \operatorname{vec}(A_{1}, \ldots, A_{p})$ [as in Lütkepohl](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Introduction_to_Multiple_Time_Series/muorJ6FHIiEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA223&bshm=nce/1). It might help if you were to write down your likelihood function $f\left(y_{T+h}|\mathbf{y}_{1:T},\mathbf{\alpha}_{1:p}\right)$ and prior $g\left(\mathbf{\alpha}_{1:p} \right)$.